# API reading error: ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api, data-manipulation

Im tryng to import some data from a API but i keep getting this error.

ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json('https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/atletas/mercado')
```

I've seen some say to use something like:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
data = json.load(open('json_file.json'))

df = pd.DataFrame(data["result"])
```

But as the data comes from a api i dont know how to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using `requests`

```
response = requests.get('https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/atletas/mercado')
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Then use `.keys()` to see what the top level of the json is

```
data.keys()
# dict_keys(['clubes', 'posicoes', 'status', 'atletas'])
```

Depending on what you want, you can do this and further manipulate your data.

```
pd.DataFrame(data['clubes'])
pd.DataFrame(data['posicoes'])
pd.DataFrame(data['status'])
pd.DataFrame(data['atletas'])
```

If you aren't that advanced yet, the above is ok. You can look into `json_normalize` as well when you start becoming more comfortable with json structures